# How to show which textfield is empty on button click?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have lots of text fields, and on Submit button click i want to show an alert message containing the names of empty textfields, any convenient way to do this without typing long lines if conditions ?

[image]

Comment: Down voting as this question does not have a specific answer.

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap There is no serial down voting. None of the answers actually do what is being asked. The OP wants an alert that shows a list of all of the fields that are empty. And besides that (but not the cause of any down votes on the answers), no one should be posting an answer to such a poor question. Answers to bad questions just encourages more bad questions.

Comment: i think if harshil or other needs to learn objective c or other tech they must have to put their own efforts to find simple solution instead of asking these baby like questions here ..

Comment: Suppose there are 2 textfield which are empty.. on click submit button, it shows alert that 1st field is empty..if user fill that and click on submit, then it shows alert for 2nd textfield... means in this way.. it check all textfield one by one.... thats  Harshal exactly looking for .......@rmaddy

Comment: @SurajSukale No. Please read the question. The OP wrote: *"i want to show an alert message containing the names of empty textfields"*. This means that want all empty field names shown at once in a single alert.

Comment: Whats poor thing in the question ? Why so much hate ?

Comment: what do you want exactly.. that have not specific answer... all empty textfield can't display in 1 pop up...according to expertise....@Harshil

Comment: @SurajSukale What? Of course it can be done. No one said it can't be done. It's actually very simple.

Comment: @Harshil There is no hate. Your question is being down voted because your question shows no effort. I politely suggest you click on the help link at the top of this page and review the section on asking questions. And many of the questions were down voted because they don't actually do what you were asking for. None of this is personal. It's just an indication of the usefulness and correctness of those answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1) If you have outlets of every textfield then you can check using if-else like

```
if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
    NSLog(@"textField is not empty");
}
```

2) You can get all subviews in array by calling `subviews` method. So you can make a method with return type BOOL something like,

```
-(BOOL)checkTextFieldIsEmpty{
    NSArray *arr = [self.view subviews];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
        if ([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *tempTextField = (UITextField*)[arr objectAtIndex:i];

            if (tempTextField.text.length >0) {
                NSLog(@"textfield is not empty");
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"textfield is empty");
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Then you can call that method on submit button click. If any textfield is empty then it willl return `NO` else `YES`. If you get Yes then go further.

**Update :**

If you want to show empty textField list on alertview then you can do something like,

```
 -(void)checkTextFieldIsEmpty{

NSArray *arr = [self.view subviews];

NSString *emptyTextFieldName = [[NSString alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {


    if ([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {


        UITextField *tempTextField = (UITextField*)[arr objectAtIndex:i];

        if (tempTextField.text.length >0) {

            NSLog(@"textfield is not empty");
        }
        else{


            NSLog(@"textfield is empty");

            emptyTextFieldName = [emptyTextFieldName stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, ",tempTextField.placeholder]];

        }


    }

}

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Empty TextFiel" message:emptyTextFieldName delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];

}
```

Comment: @Shreyank : Yeah, Second is much better.

Comment: This answer doesn't do what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I am updating accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, i tried but it didn't show the text fields's list those are empty

Comment: are your textfields empty ? Means `email,fax` should be placeholder not text

Answer (score 0):

Can't it be as simple as below?

```
NSString *errorMessage = @"Please fill data for below fields.";
int isError = 0;

if (postalCode.text.length==0) {
    errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@", errorMessage, @"Postal Code"];
    isError++;
}
if (industry.text.length==0) {
    errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@", errorMessage, @"Industry"];
    isError++;
}

// now do these steps for all fields.

if (isError>=1) {
    // show alert with errorMessage
    // also if you specify how many fields are missed, you can use isError variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take, depending on what you consider the name to be.

**1)** If the placeholder text shown in your screenshot is the name, or is close enough to the desired name, you can simply use that.  Iterate over the textfields until you find an empty one, and then show an alert based on its placeholder text.

```
NSArray *textfields = @[
    self.textfield1,
    self.textfield2,
];

for (UITextField *tf in textfields) {
    if (tf.text.length == 0) {
        // Show alert with tf.placeholder
        break;
    }
}
```

**2)** If you need specific names, you can build a dictionary which maps the names to their textfields.  You then iterate over the dictionary, looking for the appropriate textfield.

```
NSDictionary<NSString *, UITextField *> *textfieldNameMap = @{
    @"Name 1" : self.textfield1,
    @"Name 2" : self.textfield2,
};

[textfieldNameMap enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *name = (NSString *)key;
    UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)obj;
    if (tf.text.length == 0) {
       // Show alert using name
       *stop = YES;
    }
}
```

Note that the dictionary cannot use `UITextField` as the key, because that class does not conform to `NSCopying`.  Also note that the order in which textfields will be found is not deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this code for every text field of view controller in the     button action block. Something like this -                                                                          


@IBAction func SubmitButtonAction(sender: UIButton) 
 {
   if (textField.text.isEmpty)
    {
          let alert = UIAlertView()
          alert.title = "No Text"
          alert.message = "Please Enter Text In The Box"
          alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
          alert.show()
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out later  that there is no way to do this right now.

Comment: 1) This isn't an answer to your question. 2) It's simply not true. It can be done.